# Смена изображения

Tags: php, css, изображения, cookie, update

Не могу решить проблему с изображениями после `update` т.к изображения было загружено в куки браузера пока их не почистишь изображение не будет изменено. В форумах прочитал что
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/template/css/product.css?<?php echo time();?>">` должно помочь. Попробовал не помогло. Как быть?

Comment: Возможно вы путаете кэш браузера и куки HTTP. Куда именно было загружено изображение, как оно размещается на странице, и что именно вам нужно поменять/почистить?

Comment: скачайте расширения для google clear cache установите и пробуйте.Скорее всего проблема в нем.

Comment: Изображение загружается на сервер в базу попадают пути изображения с названием и выводится так:  `<img src='<?echo $img['path'] . $img['image_name'];?>'>`

Comment: @Избыток сусликов я конешно могу прочистить кэш браузера, но это надо не мне, а пользователям

Comment: Мне надо чтобы изображение изменялось в случае если его изменят без очистки кэша браузера